# MongoDB update $push with $sort to array of arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document with format:

```
{
    "_id": "test",
    "TestArr": [
        [1, 2],
        [2, 3],
        [3, 4]
    ]
}
```

I want to insert another array into the "TestArr" array and sort it by the second item in each sub array at the same time.

I have confirmed that I can do this:

```
db.ArrayTest.update(
    { "_id" : "test" },
    {
       $push: {
           "TestArr" : {
               $each : [[6,3]],
               $sort: 1 
           }
       }
    }
 )
```

This results in document:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "test", 
    "TestArr" : [
        [1.0, 7.0], 
        [2.0, 3.0], 
        [3.0, 4.0], 
        [6.0, 3.0]
   ]
}
```

What I actually want is:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "test", 
    "TestArr" : [
        [2.0, 3.0],
        [6.0, 3.0]
        [3.0, 4.0],
        [1.0, 7.0]   
   ]
}
```

$sort : 1 in that update appears to be sorting the entire sub array. I know that I can specify specific sub fields for sort using $sort : { field: 1 } when sorting array of document. Not sure how to specify sort using specific item index of sub arrays.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: You can use [`$position`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/position/) modifier to `$push` on specific index

Comment: Hello!
Is it okay for you to do the updation first and then sort the resulting array separately...like in two different queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the collection `ArrayTest` created with your sample data :

```
{
        "_id" : "test",
        "TestArr" : [
                [ 1, 7 ],
                [ 2, 3 ],
                [ 3, 4 ]
        ]
}
```

**Input Aggregate Query :**

```
db.ArrayTest.aggregate([
    {
        $match : { "_id" : "test" }
    },
    {
        $unwind : "$TestArr"
    },
    {
        $sort : { "TestArr.1" : 1 }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            _id : "$_id",
            TestArr : {$push:"$TestArr"}
        }
    }
])
```

Here we are first using `$unwind` stage and then the `$sort` stage to sort the sub arrays by the 2nd element in them.

**Output :**

```
{
    "_id" : "test",
    "TestArr" : [ 
        [ 2, 3 ],
        [ 3, 4 ],
        [ 1, 7 ]
    ]
}
```

This is the sorted array.

If the updation & sorting can be done separately, you can first insert the new sub array and then use this command to sort them.

Please try this and let us know if it worked!

Comment: I was hoping to do it in one DB interaction using $sort function of Update. Position would work but I would have to do a find, calculate the correct position and then update. 

This is probably the best approach, insert all items, then conduct sort using aggregate to unwind, sort, push back into array and update original record.